# SQL Update Query Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-update

```
UPDATE Table
SET X = 0,Y = 0
From Table 
Where X > 9.99 or Y > 9.99
```

I need to set X's value to zero if it exceeds 9.99 and set Y's value to zero if it exceeds 9.99.

How can i achieve it in SQL.

Mine seems incorrect.

Please Help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_Table
SET X = case when X > 9.99
             then 0
             else X
        end,
    Y = case when Y > 9.99
             then 0
             else Y
        end
WHERE X > 9.99 or Y > 9.99
```